# Show all movies in each theater query

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I am learning SQL and I am having trouble running a query.  I have posted a screen shot of my current query and I am getting all the results I want for movies and how I want them.  It is not showing the movies that have a total of 0 showings.  How do I include the movies that have no showings? I have included all of my query for creating tables and foreign keys.

```
 -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Options
 -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 USE dbSQL1;     -- Get out of the master database
 SET NOCOUNT ON; -- Report only errors

 -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Drop Tables
 -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  DROP TABLE TTicketPrices
  DROP TABLE TTicketSales
  DROP TABLE TShowings
  DROP TABLE TTheaters
  DROP TABLE TMovies
  DROP TABLE TTicketTypes
  DROP TABLE TScreenTypes

   -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- Step #1.1: Create Tables
   -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE TTheaters
(
      intTheaterID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
     ,strTheater            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
     ,strTheaterAddress VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
     ,strTheaterCity        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
     ,strTheaterState   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
     ,CONSTRAINT TTheaters_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTheaterID )
 )

 CREATE TABLE TScreenTypes
 (
     intScreenTypeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strScreenType      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TScreenTypes_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intScreenTypeID )
 )

 CREATE TABLE TMovies
 (
     intMovieID         INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strMovieName       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strDescription     VARCHAR(2000)   NOT NULL
    ,intRunningTime     INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TMovies_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intMovieID )
 )

 CREATE TABLE TShowings
 (
     intShowingID       INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intTheaterID       INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intScreenTypeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intMovieID         INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,dteShowDate        DATE            NOT NULL
    ,tmeShowTime        TIME            NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TMovieShowings_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intShowingID )
)

 CREATE TABLE TTicketPrices
(
     intTheaterID       INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intScreenTypeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intTicketTypeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,monTicketPrice     MONEY           NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TTicketPrices_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTheaterID, intScreenTypeID, intTicketTypeID )
)

CREATE TABLE TTicketTypes
(
     intTicketTypeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strTicketType      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL    --- Adult, Student, Child
    ,CONSTRAINT TTicketTypes_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTicketTypeID )
)

CREATE TABLE TTicketSales
(
     intTicketSaleID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intShowingID       INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intTicketTypeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,monTicketPrice     MONEY           NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TTicketSales_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTicketSaleID )
 )



-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------
-- Step #1.2: Identify and Create Foreign Keys
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------     -------
--
-- #    Child                               Parent                          Column(s)
-- -    -----                               ------                      ----     -----
 -- 1   TShowings                           TTheaters                        intTheaterID
 -- 2   TShowings                           TScreenTypess                    intScreenTypeID
 -- 3   TShowings                           TMovies                          intMovieID
-- 4    TTicketPrices                       TTheaters                       intTheaterID
-- 5    TTicketPrices                       TScreenTypes                    intScreenTypeID
-- 6    TTicketPrices                       TTicketTypes                     intTicketTypeID
-- 7    TTicketSales                        TShowings                       intShowingID
-- 8    TTicketSales                        TTicketTypes                    intTicketTypeID 

 -- 1
ALTER TABLE TShowings ADD CONSTRAINT TShowings_TTheaters_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intTheaterID ) REFERENCES TTheaters ( intTheaterID )
 -- 2
ALTER TABLE TShowings ADD CONSTRAINT TShowings_TScreenTypes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intScreenTypeID ) REFERENCES TScreenTypes ( intScreenTypeID )
-- 3
ALTER TABLE TShowings ADD CONSTRAINT TShowings_TMovies_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intMovieID ) REFERENCES TMovies ( intMovieID )
-- 4
ALTER TABLE TTicketPrices ADD CONSTRAINT TTicketPrices_TTheaters_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intTheaterID ) REFERENCES TTheaters ( intTheaterID )
-- 5
ALTER TABLE TTicketPrices ADD CONSTRAINT TTicketPrices_TScreenTypes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intScreenTypeID ) REFERENCES TScreenTypes ( intScreenTypeID )
-- 6
ALTER TABLE TTicketPrices ADD CONSTRAINT TTicketPrices_TTicketTypes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intTicketTypeID ) REFERENCES TTicketTypes ( intTicketTypeID )
-- 7
ALTER TABLE TTicketSales ADD CONSTRAINT TTicketSales_TShowings_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intShowingID ) REFERENCES TShowings ( intShowingID )
-- 8
ALTER TABLE TTicketSales ADD CONSTRAINT TTicketSale_TTicketTypes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intTicketTypeID ) REFERENCES TTicketTypes ( intTicketTypeID )
 -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------     --------
 -- Step #1.3: Add data
 -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------     --------
 INSERT INTO TTicketTypes ( intTicketTypeID, strTicketType )
 VALUES  ( 1, 'Adult' )
        ,( 2, 'Student')
        ,( 3, 'Child' )
        ,( 4, 'Senior') -- No sales for this ticket type.

 INSERT INTO TScreenTypes ( intScreenTypeID, strScreenType )
 VALUES  ( 1, 'Standard' )
    ,( 2, 'Imax')
    ,( 3, '3D' )
    ,( 4, '4D' )    -- No showings for this screen type

 INSERT INTO TTheaters ( intTheaterID, strTheater, strTheaterAddress, strTheaterCity, strTheaterState )
 VALUES  ( 1, 'Old Time Theater', '100 Main Street', 'Covington', 'KY' )
        ,( 2, 'Super 8 Theater', '8 Your Street ', 'Your Town', 'OH' )
        ,( 3, 'Main Street Theater', '203 High Road ', 'New Town', 'OH' )
        ,( 4, 'Fun Time Theater', '20 New Avenue ', 'My Town', 'IN' ) -- No showings for this theater

 INSERT INTO TMovies ( intMovieID, strMovieName, strDescription,  intRunningTime )
VALUES   ( 1, 'Long Journey Home' , 'Heartfeld movie ... ', 165)
        ,( 2, 'Antartica', 'Educational movie ....', 205)
        ,( 3, 'Drama on the High Seas', 'Dramatic movie ....', 175)
        ,( 4, 'Aliens vs. Zombies', 'Scary movie about.....', 105)
        ,( 5, 'All About Penguins', 'Educational movie.....', 135) -- No showings for this movie

 INSERT INTO TShowings ( intShowingID, intTheaterID,  intMovieID, intScreenTypeID, dteShowDate, tmeShowTime )
 VALUES  
          ( 1, 1, 1, 1, '07/1/2015', '12:30')
         ,( 2, 1, 1, 1, '07/1/2015', '17:15')
         ,( 3, 1, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '22:00')

         ,( 4, 1, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '11:00')
         ,( 5, 1, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '15:15')
         ,( 6, 1, 2, 3, '07/1/2015', '20:50')
         ,( 7, 1, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '11:15')
         ,( 8, 1, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '16:15')
         ,( 9, 1, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '22:45')
         ,( 10, 2, 1, 2, '07/2/2015', '11:30')
         ,( 11, 2, 1, 2, '07/2/2015', '17:15')
         ,( 12, 2, 1, 2, '07/2/2015', '23:00')
         ,( 13, 2, 2, 2, '07/2/2015', '11:00')
         ,( 14, 2, 2, 1, '07/2/2015', '16:15')
         ,( 15, 2, 2, 3, '07/2/2015', '20:50')
         ,( 16, 2, 3, 1, '07/2/2015', '12:15')
         ,( 17, 2, 3, 1, '07/2/2015', '17:15')
         ,( 18, 2, 3, 1, '07/2/2015', '23:45')
         ,( 19, 2, 1, 1, '07/1/2015', '12:00')
         ,( 20, 3, 3, 3, '07/1/2015', '17:45')
         ,( 21, 3, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '22:10')
         ,( 22, 3, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '12:00')
         ,( 23, 3, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '16:15')
         ,( 24, 3, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '22:50')
         ,( 25, 3, 2, 1, '07/1/2015', '11:45')
         ,( 26, 3, 3, 2, '07/1/2015', '16:25')
         ,( 27, 3, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '23:45')
         ,( 28, 3, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '12:00')
         ,( 29, 1, 2, 3, '07/1/2015', '17:45')
         ,( 30, 1, 4, 1, '07/1/2015', '22:10')
         ,( 31, 1, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '12:00')
         ,( 32, 2, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '16:15')
         ,( 33, 2, 4, 1, '07/1/2015', '22:50')
         ,( 34, 2, 1, 1, '07/1/2015', '11:45')
         ,( 35, 3, 2, 3, '07/1/2015', '16:25')
         ,( 36, 3, 3, 1, '07/1/2015', '23:45')
         ,( 37, 1, 1, 3, '07/3/2015', '22:10')
         ,( 38, 1, 3, 1, '07/3/2015', '12:00')
         ,( 39, 2, 3, 1, '07/3/2015', '16:15')
         ,( 40, 2, 3, 2, '07/3/2015', '22:50')
         ,( 41, 2, 1, 1, '07/3/2015', '11:45')
         ,( 42, 3, 2, 3, '07/3/2015', '16:25')
         ,( 43, 3, 3, 1, '07/3/2015', '23:45')

 INSERT INTO TTicketPrices ( intTheaterID, intScreenTypeID, intTIcketTypeID, monTicketPrice )
  VALUES   ( 1, 1, 1, 11.00)  -- Standard Screen, Adult
          ,( 1, 1, 2, 8.00) -- Standard Screen, Student
          ,( 1, 1, 3, 6.50) -- Standard Screen, Child
          ,( 1, 1, 4, 7.50) -- Standard Screen, Senior
          ,( 1, 2, 1, 12.00)    -- Imax Screen, Adult
          ,( 1, 2, 2, 9.00) -- Imax Screen, Student
          ,( 1, 2, 3, 7.00) -- Imax Screen, Child
          ,( 1, 2, 4, 7.25) -- IMax Screen, Senior
          ,( 1, 3, 1, 15.00)    -- 3D, Adult
          ,( 1, 3, 2, 12.00)    -- 3D, Student
          ,( 1, 3, 3, 10.00)    -- 3D, Child
          ,( 1, 3, 4, 10.50)    -- 3D Screen, Senior
 -- Theater 2
          ,( 2, 1, 1, 11.50)  -- Standard Screen, Adult
          ,( 2, 1, 2, 8.50) -- Standard Screen, Student
          ,( 2, 1, 3, 6.50) -- Standard Screen, Child
          ,( 2, 2, 1, 12.50)    -- Imax Screen, Adult
          ,( 2, 2, 2, 9.50) -- Imax Screen, Student
          ,( 2, 2, 3, 7.50) -- Imax Screen, Child
          ,( 2, 3, 1, 15.50)    -- 3D, Adult
          ,( 2, 3, 2, 12.50)    -- 3D, Student
          ,( 2, 3, 3, 10.50)    -- 3D, Child
          ,( 2, 4, 1, 15.50)    -- 4D, Adult
          ,( 2, 4, 2, 12.50)    -- 4D, Student
          ,( 2, 4, 3, 10.50)    -- 4D, Child
 -- Theater 3
         ,( 3, 1, 1, 11.50)  -- Standard Screen, Adult
         ,( 3, 1, 2, 7.50)  -- Standard Screen, Student
         ,( 3, 1, 3, 5.50)  -- Standard Screen, Child
         ,( 3, 2, 1, 11.50) -- Imax Screen, Adult
         ,( 3, 2, 2, 9.00)  -- Imax Screen, Student
         ,( 3, 2, 3, 7.00)  -- Imax Screen, Child
         ,( 3, 3, 1, 15.00) -- 3D, Adult
         ,( 3, 3, 2, 13.00) -- 3D, Student
         ,( 3, 3, 3, 9.50)  -- 3D, Child

 INSERT INTO TTicketSales ( intTicketSaleID, intShowingID, intTicketTypeID, monTicketPrice )
VALUES   ( 1, 1, 1, 11 )
        ,( 2, 26, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 3, 28, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 4, 5, 2, 8 )
        ,( 5, 26, 3, 7 )    
        ,( 6, 12, 1, 12.5 )
        ,( 7, 13, 2, 9.5 )
        ,( 8, 7, 1, 11 )
        ,( 9, 2, 2, 8 )
        ,( 10, 16, 3, 6.5 )
        ,( 11, 8, 1, 11 )
        ,( 12, 22, 2, 7.5 )
        ,( 13, 19, 3, 6.5 )
        ,( 14, 17, 3, 6.5 )
        ,( 15, 9, 1, 11 )
        ,( 16, 21, 2, 7.5 )
        ,( 17, 27, 2, 7.5 )
        ,( 18, 34, 3, 6.5 )
        ,( 19, 13, 3, 7.5 )
        ,( 20, 11, 1, 12.5 )
        ,( 21, 19, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 22, 17, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 23, 1, 2, 8 )
        ,( 24, 36, 3, 5.5 )
        ,( 25, 11, 2, 9.5 )
        ,( 26, 17, 2, 8.5 )
        ,( 27, 20, 2, 13 )
        ,( 28, 21, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 29, 22, 3, 5.5 )
        ,( 30, 21, 3, 5.5 )
        ,( 31, 9, 3, 6.5 )
        ,( 32, 7, 2, 8 )
        ,( 33, 2, 1, 11 )
        ,( 34, 3, 1, 11 )
        ,( 35, 14, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 36, 30, 1, 15 )
        ,( 37, 15, 1, 15.5 )
        ,( 38, 29, 1, 15 )
        ,( 39, 6, 1, 15 )   
        ,( 40, 27, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 41, 36, 1, 11.5 )
        ,( 42, 6, 2, 12 )
        ,( 43, 10, 3, 7.5 )
        ,( 44, 27, 3, 5.5 )


SELECT
      TT.intTheaterID
     ,TT.strTheater
     ,TM.intMovieID
     ,TM.strMovieName
     ,SUM( TM.intMovieID ) AS intTotalMovies
FROM
      TTheaters     AS  TT  --A
     ,TShowings     AS  TS  --B
     ,TMovies       AS  TM  --C
WHERE
     --A to B
          TT.intTheaterID       =   TS.intTheaterID

     --B to C
     AND  TS.intMovieID         =   TM.intMovieID
GROUP BY
     TT.intTheaterID
    ,TT.strTheater
    ,TM.intMovieID
    ,TM.strMovieName

ORDER BY
     TT.intTheaterID
```

Comment: Could you post your query here as well please?  if possible, in a separate code block?

Comment: No pictures please. Text.

Comment: Where are you learning SQL?   No one should be teaching those old-style joins any more.   I would find a new teacher.

Comment: I'm also interested in @TabAlleman question, if you are willing to tell.

Comment: I'm just learning we are learning old and new syntax. I appreciate the help the answer below worked and made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use old style joins. With that, here is an explanation.

Since you want to count the number of showings for each movie, we need to `COUNT` not `SUM`. Secondly, we need to do this on the correct field. Summing a unique identifier is almost NEVER something that would be done since it's an arbitrary value. Instead, since you want to see how many times a movie is being shown, `COUNT` the unique identifier that is related to the showing, not the movie itself. `COUNT(TS.intShowingID) AS totalShowings`

Lastly, since a movie can have 0 showings, we need to use the `TMovies` table as the base table to select from, and `LEFT JOIN` to it so that we don't remove / limit / filter any of the movies out.

```
      TMovies AS  TM
      LEFT JOIN TShowings TS ON TS.intMovieID = TM.intMovieID
      LEFT JOIN TTheaters TT on TT.intTheaterID = TS.intTheaterID
```

Now, put it all together....

```
SELECT
      TT.intTheaterID
     ,TT.strTheater
     ,TM.intMovieID
     ,TM.strMovieName
     ,COUNT(TS.intShowingID) AS totalShowings
FROM
      TMovies AS  TM
      LEFT JOIN TShowings TS ON TS.intMovieID = TM.intMovieID
      LEFT JOIN TTheaters TT on TT.intTheaterID = TS.intTheaterID
GROUP BY
    TM.intMovieID
    ,TT.intTheaterID
    ,TT.strTheater
    ,TM.strMovieName

ORDER BY
     TT.intTheaterID
```

You will see that intMoveID 5 doesn't have any theaters associated with it, because it isn't being shown anywhere.

If you wanted to show all the theaters (like the Fun Time Theater which has no showings) you can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. There are many join options which you should study hard on. It's a very critical aspect to the structured query language.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I am new to aggregates and Sub-queries and that is the best explanation I have received yet.

Comment: Glad it helped @BradWethington